# OSQA port on Google App Engine using django-nonrel

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, osqa

I've been developing a website on Google App Engine using Python and I need a Q&A system. [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net) seems to be the best option available. As it is basically a Django app, can anybody give me some pointers on porting OSQA to GAE? Also, I came to know about the [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) project. Any detailed tutorials as how to port OSQA to django-nonrel?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it would probably to run it on GAE's CloudSQL with Django (not non-rel).

Django-nonrel is very limited when it comes to SQL style queries.  If OSQA requires complex queries, or even JOINs, there's a good chance you'd need to change the way the data is modeled, and the way queries are made.  This could be a very significant effort, it's hard to tell without being familiar with the package.

Django apps that make very little use of data modelling tends to port over fairly easily to Django-nonrel.  Stuff like the templates for the UI may just work.